# The sequence $n^2+1$ hasn´t a finite number of terms with $\omega(n^2+1)\geq 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From Wikipedia:

> " Henryk Iwaniec showed that there are infinitely many numbers of the form $n^2+1$ with at most two prime factors."

But is the set of all natural numbers of the form $n^2+1$ such that  $\omega(n^2+1)\geq 3$ also infinite?

This seems to be trivially true, but how to prove?

$\omega(m)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $m$.

Comment: An impressive theorem !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

If $n$ is odd then $n^2+1$ is even.

If $n\equiv 2\pmod 5$ then $n^2+1$ is divisible by $5$.

If $n\equiv 5\pmod {13}$ then $n^2+1$ is divisible by $13$.

Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to show there are infinitely many $n$  satisfying all three congruences.  (Indeed $n\equiv 57\pmod {130}$ works).

Using primes of the form $4n+1$ it's easy to generalize this from $3$ prime factors to as many as you like.